# Hadoop MapReduce InputFormat Deprecated?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to implement a custom (service) input source for a Hadoop MapReduce app. I google'd and SO'd and found that one way to proceed is to implement a custom InputFormat. Is that correct?

Apparently according to http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html InputFormat's methods getRecordReader() and getSplits() are deprecated. What's the replacement?

Hadoop's WordCount example still uses the same...

Comment: Your problem is actually in the lurch between versions. Much of the problem with `0.20.2` (the latest stable release) is it explicitly deprecates functionality without intra-version replacement. Such is the case with `MultipleOutputs` and nearly the entirety of `org.apache.hadoop.mapred`. This seems to indicate a major restructuring of the API, which I've been following. (Answer forthcoming, once I compile enough source information.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation:](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/deprecated-list.html)

> Deprecated Interfaces
>
> ...
>
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat
>
> *Use [InputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html) instead.*
>
> ...

Due to the weird deprecation behavior with `0.20.2` and even weirder suggestion to use an implementation after deprecating an interface, I dug a little deeper. This interface is still present in `0.21.0`, with the deprecation tag removed. I couldn't find a comparable interface in the trunk at the time of this writing.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented a custom InputFormat and am glad to know 0.21.0 "undeprecates" it. :D

Answer (score 5):

Although Hadoop still uses things from the mapred package internally, from the user's perspective, they should pretty much all be considered deprecated.  Hadoop is extremely lacking when it comes to documentation and their examples all tend to be outdated.  Luckily, when you're really stuck there's always stackoverflow

Comment: +1 insightful. The lack of documentation and a _consistent_ API is rather frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

What happened is, in 0.20 they deprecated mapred classes and introduced a new API. However, new API lacked few core features, and thus old API was 'undeprecated' in the latest release. It is advisable to use old API as most likely it will be the one that is here to stay.